# Show warning about author and question is the same user

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

When reviewing low quality post I've came across [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8120042).

At first sight it looks like answer (and only after reading last 2 lines it becomes clear that it's just OP commenting on the answer).

Knowing in advance that OP is answering his/her own question it would be easier (and faster) to notice that it's a commentary not an answer.

If you want to check who's the asker you need to scroll down to question (which can be annoying with longer answers).

It would be nice to have visual notification above the answer saying "This is OP answering his/her own question".

Comment: The name/avatar/etc has a highlighted background, so you immediately know it's the asker.